# Angular acceleration problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

We know when direction of velocity changes even if speed is constant it is still accelerating with respect to an external non-inertial frame but when we say for a constant angular velocity angular acceleration is zero, how is this possible that angular acceleration is zero?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  If the direction of velocity changes then velocity is not constant.  And who says that constant angular velocity means zero acceleration?

Comment: Read it again now I made some changes

Comment: Constant velocity --> acceleration is zero.  Constant angular velocity --> angular acceleration is zero.   The direction of the angular velocity does not change, nor does its magnitude.

Comment: Dude for constant velocity acceleration is only zero when motion is linear not for rotating bodies and I am asking how can angular acceleration be zero

Comment: Do you actually *know* what angular acceleration is?

Comment: Ofcourse I know that's the only reason I asked it and it seems you are pretty much cofused, velocity is vector not scalar so changes in direction is also considered to be change in acceleration

Comment: You just proved that you don't know what angular acceleration is.  Get a physics book, and carefully read the chapter on rotational kinematics.

Answer (score 1):

;angular  displacement = angle rotated by the body with respect to its axis

angular velocity = rate of change in angular displacement

angular acceleration =rate of change in angular velocity

---

The acceleration of the rotating body have two components :

- tangential acceleration (acting tangentially to the path which changes the speed of the object)
- centripetal acceleration (acting towards the center which keeps the direction changing)

---

angular acceleration = (tangential acceleration)/(radius)

in your case the object is rotating with constant speed so tangential acceleration is zero so angular acceleration is zero.

for concepts [Read the uniform and non-uniform circular motion part in this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion)

Answer (score 0):

Angular velocity and angular acceleration are both in a direction parallel to the axis of rotation. If the magnitude of the angular velocity is constant, and the rotating body is not precessing, then the angular acceleration is $0$. You define your angular velocity $\omega$ to be perpendicular to your radius at all points, because it's defined as the cross product of your linear velocity $v$ with the radius of the sample particle $m_a$'s motion.

Read Taylor. He does a very good job of building the framework for dealing with rotating bodies.

Comment: I think you should specify you're talking about the *vectors*. Your reference to 'Taylor" is rather oblique. Which Taylor? What book or paper?

Comment: Book, simply titled Classical Mechanics.

Comment: Hey one more thing it doesn't precess only when it is spinning is it true

Comment: It precesses only when spinning. In the derivation for precessing motion (see Euler's equations), the angular velocities for 3 orthogonal axes are required in general.